# Need help about linux mint's start menu is gone

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have been using Linux mint for a year and it works flawlessly but now when I power on my laptop and log in to my account I get no start menu, no panel, and no title bar and plank that have 4 apps including terminal and it's the only way to run the terminal ( i tried ctrl + alt + t and it doesn't work )

and when I reboot using the reboot command and log in as a guest everything works

so how can I get everything back to normal ???

thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egPyB.png)

Comment: What's your desktop software? I don't recognize it from the screenshot.  I eg. have XFCE4, and in your case I would stop the graphical environment, and from a console session I would clear $HOME/.cache, restart the desktop.  If that didn't help, again from a console session, rename $HOME/.config/xfce4 and restart.  Did you run an upgrade recently?

Comment: it's cinnamon and actually, I fixed I just type cinnamon and everything back now the problem is every time I log in I have to explicitly run cinnamon  so I made it run at startup

Comment: Had the same thing with XFCE4.  Just needed to clean the cache.